# Fancy Slider codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a trouble with this code ;
I want to added other images that I commented with comment including my name 

 but It doesn't work , this is the original link of the code snippet

https://codepen.io/suez/pen/wMMgXp

This is the modified snippet
https://codepen.io/ahmedch1/pen/BXReBN
I get always this error

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1179,
  "colno": 25
}
```

You can run the code snippet above in order to get more details
Thanks in advance

This modification is after being solved thanks to @slientw

https://codepen.io/ahmedch1/pen/BXReBN

Comment: This means your selector `$activeControlsBg` does not refer to an actual node in the HTML - I'd take a look at that selector and make sure it's targeting the node you're trying to target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the example provided, the script is expecting to have the same number of `fnc-nav__bgs` as slides.

So, if you add 2 more divs inside `div.fnc-nav__bgs` on line 163 of your HTML, it works correctly.

Example:

```
<div class="fnc-nav__bgs">
  <div class="fnc-nav__bg m--navbg-green m--active-nav-bg"></div>
  <div class="fnc-nav__bg m--navbg-dark"></div>
  <div class="fnc-nav__bg m--navbg-red"></div>
  <div class="fnc-nav__bg m--navbg-blue"></div>
  <div class="fnc-nav__bg m--navbg-blue"></div> <!-- Added -->
  <div class="fnc-nav__bg m--navbg-blue"></div> <!-- Added -->
</div>
```